# As per CSP, can an allowed JavaScript code run another JavaScript code downloading from different domain on a Web page?

Tags: javascript, browser, content-security-policy

I have a JavaScript code snippet embedded inline on a page that downloads and appends to body my main JavaScript code from a different CDN, `cdnjs.com/xyz/main.js`. So far this has worked fine for my customers. `main.js` is able to make AJAX calls and perform normally.

- Is my assumption correct that clients must have allowed in their CSP policy the `cdnjs.com` domain? And this process is a required for a setup like mine?
- If I change my main JavaScript to **additionally** download and run new JavaScript code from another domain, `cdnjs2.com/abc/new.js`, will this new JavaScript code run fine and be able to make AJAX calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is my assumption correct that clients must have allowed in their CSP policy the cdnjs.com domain?

Well, since by default there is no CSP policy for a page, it would be truer to say they must not forbid that domain if they have a CSP.

> If I change my main JavaScript to additionally download and run new JavaScript code from another domain…

When there is a CSP, every location that JS is sourced from must be allowed, even if the code that sources it is from an allowed location.

Comment: For your second answer then, it will also follow suite on first – when clients are not specifically disabling `cdnjs2.com`, 1st script downloading 2nd script should also work and 2nd script can make AJAX calls, when there’s no CSP policy override to default on the page?

Comment: If a CSP is added and limits the scripts to only ones sourced from `cdnjs.com` then attempting to load a script from `cdnjs2.com` will fail. If no CSP is added then there are no restrictions on where scripts can be loaded from.